# Index parsing issue using DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, java-8

I am creating an appointment app that pulls from a database of names. I have a screen created that lets you modify an appointment. I want it to populate the already existing appointment to be changed. All of the other fields are working, but for modifyDate (which is my DatePicker), it returns an error.

Populates the information in the modify appointment screen:

```
public void setAppointment(Appointment appointment, int index) {
selectedAppointment = appointment;
selectedIndex = index;

Appointment newAppointment = (Appointment) appointment;

DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS");

this.modifyContactNameText.setText(newAppointment.getContact());
this.modifyTitleText.setText((newAppointment.getTitle()));
this.modifyURLText.setText((newAppointment.getUrl()));
this.modifyTypeText.setText((newAppointment.getType()));
this.modifyDescriptionComboBox.setValue((newAppointment.getDescription()));
this.modifyLocationComboBox.setValue((newAppointment.getLocation()));
this.modifyDate.setValue(LocalDate.parse(newAppointment.getStart(), format)); <----issue line
// I originally tried it like this:
// this.modifyDate.setValue((newAppointment.getStart())); 
// but that returned the time and date, and I just need the date
```

Modify Appointment Handler

```
    @FXML
void modifyAppointmentHandler(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();     
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/View_Controller/ModifyAppointment.fxml"));
        loader.load();
        ModifyAppointmentController controller = loader.getController();
        Appointment appointment=appointmentTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
     
        int index = appointmentTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        controller.setAppointment(appointment, index);  <----issue line
     
        stage=(Stage) modifyAppointmentButton.getScene().getWindow();
        Parent scene = loader.getRoot();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(scene));
        stage.show();
        
    }
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-07-15 13:00' could not be parsed at index 16
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
at View_Controller.ModifyAppointmentController.setAppointment(ModifyAppointmentController.java:275)
at View_Controller.AppointmentScreenController.modifyAppointmentHandler(AppointmentScreenController.java:206)
... 58 more
```

Example of what it looks like, I got the location and destination filled in but need date,start ,end[image]:

Comment: Looks if your Timestamps missing the seconds. Did you try to change the line DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS");
 to DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
?

Comment: that worked! Thank you so much I knew it had to be something simple I was over looking.

Answer (score 1):

Index 16 refers to the format string specifically the last colon which is not present in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Looks if your Timestamps missing the seconds. Try to change the line `DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS");` to `DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");`